# Descriptor error: Unsupported class file major version 61

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, java-17

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WAGe.png) 
I am getting a error: `Unsupported class file major version 61` while running command:
`mvn clean install -DskipTests`

This error occurs when the program is running on java versions below JDK 17.

JDK is set to version 17 ,still i am getting this error.

Please let me know what I am missing!!

Comment: If you like to use recent JDK's use most recent versions of plugin instead of old ones https://maven.apache.org/plugins/ because version 3.6.0 is of 2018!...

Comment: Make sure the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Runner | **JRE** is set to a JDK not lower than 17 version.

Comment: Worked for me by adding the plugin mentioned here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60861485/maven-plugin-plugin3-2descriptor-failed-index-22273-out-of-bounds-for-length

Answer (score 0):

Use the version **3.6.4** or higher of [`maven-plugin-plugin`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-plugin-plugin) that is compatible with Java 17. Currently, the newest version is [**3.10.2**](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-plugin-plugin/3.10.2).

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.2</version>
</plugin>
```